# How to display images in React Native which are stored using nodejs + multer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I have used nodejs multer for file upload but I am not able to display the images in react native app why so? Please see screenshots and code below:

React native app (home.js):

```
const DisplayImages = ({url, name}) => {

    console.log("imgr url: ", url)

    return(
         <TouchableOpacity>
            <View style={{borderRadius: 10}}>
                <Image
                    source={{
                    uri: url,
                    }}
                    style={{ width: 100, height: 100, justifyContent: 'center', marginTop: 15, alignSelf: 'center' }}
                />
                <Text>{name}</Text>
            </View>
         </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
```

upload.js:

```
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'public/images/');
    },

    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        console.log("multer file", file);
        cb(null, file.originalname + '-' + new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, '-'));
    }
});

module.exports = multer({
    storage,
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5
    }
});
```

server.js:

```
app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cors());

// app.use(express.static('./public'));
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Welcome to API\'s'));

app.post('/uploads', upload.single('photo') , (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("request file: ", req.file);

    const {name} = req.body;

    const newImage = new Image({
        name: name,
        url: req.file.path
    })

    newImage.save()
        .then((image) => {
            console.log(image);
            res.status(201).json({
                message: 'New image created'
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            })
        });

})
```

Above code is not working all other API endpoints are working but when I got to browser for accessing images then it says `Cannot GET` why so?

Comment: can u show the exact error message plz?

Comment: && what does cores() exactly define?

Comment: you have to provide public path of server if you are using local server